# Is there a rough rule for heatsink size?

Tags: heatsink

Is there a simple rule that could be used to size a heatsink without fan using just the wattage and/or how hot a component would go? I understand heatsinks are in their own universe as there are many types, profiles, materials, etc. Lots of calculation I wouldn't even know where to start with. I'm just thinking if there is something like "for *n* wattage you need *x* cm*2* of heatsink," or for each 1W you need x cm2 *just a rough figure*.

Comment: In a word -- no, or at least not if by "simple" you mean what I'm thinking.  It's complicated, with many possible tradeoffs that affect everything in the thermal path between your component junctions (assuming you're talking semiconductors) and the ambient air. You _can_ use a resistor - current - voltage analogy for this, and that simplifies things a lot, but you still have to work it all out and suffer some slings and arrows in the process.

Comment: No. Wattage doesn't even determine how much a component heats up by. It's the wattage *and* the thermal resistance of the package.

Comment: I think [en.wikipedia's article on *heat sink*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink) better than half decent.

Comment: Very rough for hobbyist use only: 1 W/in2, assuming small fins, not so hot it will burn you. If you are designing a product, learn how to do the calculations. If you are unsure, attach a chassis mount resistor and run some tests.

Answer (score 3):

The simple rule for commercial heat sinks (like the finned kind) is that you read the datasheet for the heatsink in  question and interpret and apply the characteristics shown for your situation.

If you "wouldn't even know where to start", some manufacturers publish [detailed handbooks](https://www.mouser.com/catalog/supplier/library/pdf/Aavidselectionguide.pdf) on how to do the above, which is slightly (but not much) more involved than taking the datasheet degrees/W thermal resistance numbers and multiplying them by the dissipation, either for natural convection or using air flow numbers.

To do it from scratch with a randomly shaped piece of metal of whatever emissivity, orientation, etc. is not simple at all and involves fluid mechanics (which has different regimes of flow- eg. turbulent vs. laminar flow) as well as considerations of and significant radiative or conductive cooling.

The main other consideration (and this is up to you) is to determine the maximum allowable temperature rise of whatever it is that you are cooling (for reliability you'll typically want to operate **well** under the 'absolute maximum' junction temperature) and the worse case ambient temperature. Then you can figure the thermal resistance from the junction to the case and thence the heatsink, and then determine the required performance of the heatsink itself to the ambient.

For something very simple like a relatively thick highly conductive metal plate mounted (say) vertically, you should be able to find some graphs or a [calculator](https://www.heatsinkcalculator.com/flat-plate-heat-sink-calculator.html) to roughly tell you the temperature rise (assuming the plate is isothermal or perhaps adding spreading resistance factors).

I recall a design I did some decades ago that had a 5W thyristor and I wanted to maintain the junction temperature at less than 100°C in a 55°C ambient. The calculator (assuming dissipation primarily from one vertically mounted side) and 3mm thick 6061 aluminum. The calculator agrees with my memory that roughly 150mm square works. Some of the [math](https://www.heatsinkcalculator.com/blog/how-to-design-a-flat-plate-heat-sink/) is explained at the link given.

Answer (score 0):

If you state the material out of which the heat sink is made. And you roughly calculate the exposed area of the sink. Then after assuming that the temperature of the chip is the temperature of the heat sink you can use the heat current formula (rate at which heat is dissipated):

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=-\frac{kAΔT}{Δx}$$

Where,

- A means Area (had to be flat area for precision but it will not create much deviation)
- k mean Thermal Conductivity ([0.99 cal/s for copper](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/thrcn.html))
- ΔT (T2-T1) means the temperature difference between the temperature of the heat sink and air
- Δx means the thickness of the heatsink (this is what i was saying about flat surfaces)
- AND dQ/dt is the rate of cooling per sec.

You will need to check how high the temperature could go and at what rate (dQ/dt)

Check everything put it in the formula keep A and Δx as variables. You should get what you need. 
Hope it helps. Sorry for bad formatting I'm new to this network.

Comment: (Is that *flat & horizontal in non-moving air*?)

Comment: @greybeard Yes, with moving air the cooling should incease. (question: without fan)

Comment: @greybeard I'm sorry but the question clearly asks for that only. A "close approximation". That's the closest we can get with this. Thanks for the hint mate :) My bad

Comment: (Still knowing little about dissipation of heat, but I think there are two *area*s with potential for confusion: *cross section* of a thermal conductor, and *area of a plate used as a heat sink*, perpendicular to thickness.)